# Reading only certain parts of a file and counting the number of elements

Tags: python

here is the file that I want to read off of. (cube.obj)

```
#cube
v 0.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 1.0
v 0.0 0.0 1.0
v 0.0 1.0 1.0
v 0.0 1.0 0.0
v 1.0 1.0 0.0
v 1.0 1.0 1.0

f 1 2 3 4
f 6 7 8 5
f 2 3 8 7
f 1 4 5 6
f 3 4 5 8
f 1 2 7 6
```

And I'm trying to count the number of elements in this part:

```
f 1 2 3 4
f 6 7 8 5
f 2 3 8 7
f 1 4 5 6
f 3 4 5 8
f 1 2 7 6
```

So this case would be 30. Notice this is also counting f as an element

This is what I've got so far.

```
def count_numOfFace(f):
    with open(f) as fin:
        ct = 0
        for line in fin:
            if line.strip():
                if line.split()[0] == 'f':
                     # need help here
```

I'm so puzzled for this question.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What have you already tried in your loop to count the elements?

Comment: I've tried putting ct += len(line) for the part, but it gives the wrong output

Answer (score 3):

That's a good start.

```
for line in fin:
    toks = line.split()
    if toks and toks[0] == 'f':
        ct += len(toks) - 1
```

You don't want to count the length of the line - which is the number of characters (including spaces).  You want to count the number of items you split out of it (minus the first one, the 'f').  If you don't save the result of line.split(), you lose that number.

toks will be a list of strings, like `['f', '1', '2', '3', '4']`

Comment: Thanks for the such a fast feedback. I got my code to work. One more thing though. So I could use line.split() method to read a line of a file and store it as an array right?

Comment: Definitely, ['f', '1', '2', '3', '4'] is all the elements of your line in one list.  If you need to do anything with the numbers, don't forget to cast them to an integer - like int(toks[1])

Answer (score 1):

I think the following might work:

```
def count_numOfFace(f):
    with open(f) as fin:
        ct = 0
        for line in fin:
            sline = line.strip()
            if sline:
                ssline = sline.split(' ')
                if ssline[0] == 'f':
                     ct += len(ssline)
```

The number of elements should equal the length of the array resulting from splitting on space.